# Trying to simplify my php code (serialize)

Tags: php, serialization

The idea is to hide an element if data is null, my php code (below) works but all together I have 240 lines, and I think there must be a way to simplify.

Here is an example of the code I have:

```
if (trim($GLOBALS["s101"])){} else{echo "<style type='text/css'>#s101{display:none}</style>";};
if (trim($GLOBALS["s102"])){} else{echo "<style type='text/css'>#s102{display:none}</style>";};
if (trim($GLOBALS["s103"])){} else{echo "<style type='text/css'>#s103{display:none}</style>";};
if (trim($GLOBALS["s104"])){} else{echo "<style type='text/css'>#s104{display:none}</style>";};
if (trim($GLOBALS["s105"])){} else{echo "<style type='text/css'>#s105{display:none}</style>";};
if (trim($GLOBALS["s106"])){} else{echo "<style type='text/css'>#s106{display:none}</style>";};
```

The common characteristic of the above elements is the class : .sections.

So, my question is : Could a single line replaces all the lines above, and what would it be? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The first solution provided by Vick works (he deleted the answer though, I Wonder why. Thank Vick! His solution is :

foreach($GLOBALS as $key => $value) {
    if(!trim($value)) {
        echo "<style type='text/css'>#$key{display:none}</style>";
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `$GLOBALS`.  What you should probably be doing is putting all of these items into an array, rather than as a series of 240 different variables.

So build an array, let's call it `$s_array`.

You can than easily loop over the array to output:

```
foreach($s_array as $value) {
    echo '<style type="text/css">' . $value . ' {display:none}</style>';  
}
```

Or even better yet, you define a CSS class and stop the madness of all the repeated style blocks. Then apply that class to all these DOM elements that you are currently assigning CSS styles to by id.

Comment: @user3371049 Yes it will not work with your code as is.  I am suggesting a significant simplification to your current approach of polluting the global space with a series of `$s*` variables.  You would have no need for any of that if you simply applied a class to the DOM elements to add this CSS style and/or place as these variables into an array.

Comment: @user3371049 So bottom line is that you could easily replace all of this just by defining a class-based style like this: `.s_elements {display:none;}` and adding `class='s_elements"` to each one of the `s*` DOM elements that are created.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop
as well as below :

```
<?php
 for ($i=1;$i<10;$i++):
  if (trim($GLOBALS["s10".$i])){} 
      else{echo "<style type='text/css'>#s10".$i."{display:none}</style>";};


 endfor;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($GLOBALS as $key => $value) {
if(!trim($value)) {
    echo "<style type='text/css'>#$key{display:none}</style>";
}
}
```

This solution was provided by Vick, althought, he deleted it (I Wonder why). It works perfectly well. It replaces 240 lines of php code! Thanks Vick!

Comment: If you have variables in the global scope in addition to your `$s*` variables, you would be echoing a style for them as well, so use this with great caution.

Comment: Mike, you are right, I  just faced the issue, and fixed it. I am not a programmer, so sometimes I have hard time to fully understand the explanations! So I did not understand the explanations you provided above...  I go by examples :) and I am capable of implementing them.